# how can i create email group in app and send email in group

Tags: android

i have sent many email from android application but using one or two email id at a time.
but how can i create group in application and send email in group from the application.

i am using the following code to send email to one email id..

please help me guys..if any modification is required to this code or i have to add something for that..

```
Intent sendIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
 sendIntent.setType("text/html");
 sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "example@gmail.com");
            sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hello world");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```